# What is the most suitable PM tool for a software agency?

Tags: reporting

I'm trying to research what tool would be the most compatible software we can use as a software agency. I tried several tools and it took a lot of time to get familiar with them (and discover all the features). So I decided to ask for help. I'll describe our most painful challenges, our current solution, and the desired goal.

---

### The most painful challenges

Probably the **top 1 challenge** is the never-ending fight with **resource management**:

- As an agency, we have billable and non-billable people. The billable ones should be assigned to clients' projects, while the non-billable ones are typically managed by internal tasks (e.g. *"prepare a blog post"*).
- Billable people usually have different capacities which need to be respected. Typically around 30 hours a week.
- Billable people also have target allocation. Typically 80 % should be billable, and 20 % should be non-billable.
- Billable people also have target utilization. Utilization should range somewhere between 80-90 % (of the 80% billable allocation), so that the developers are not overheated, but still profitable.
- Now clients' projects typically have some need for resources. The time-framed projects typically have a PM and some devs. Those long-running agile projects have PO, SM, and some devs and designers.
- Not all projects can afford the full-time allocation of all the required people, so some of the billable people participate in multiple projects with different utilization.
- We need to monitor the state from a tactical view (usually 4-weeks ahead, more precisely) and a strategic view (usually several months ahead, less precisely).
- If we won't match the conditions above, we cannot be sustainably viable in the long run.

Another, the **top 2 challenge** is a **high-level monitoring/reporting**:

- The projects must be completely delivered on time and within budget. This usually differs whether it's a waterfall project (strict constraints) or agile development (budget restrictions and milestones). And we should be able to identify troubles sooner than when the deadline occurs.
- The resources must be used accordingly to the plan (see the points above) and if not, we should be able to detect it in advance.
- Other objectives (e.g. clients' happiness) must be monitored to identify any problems within the company that need attention. Typical key results include some activities with KPIs where RAG definitions will tell us what should we focus on.

I could continue with other challenges, but as I was writing it, I decided to stick with these two for now, which are most important to me now.

---

### The current solution

As a PM tool, we currently use ClickUp, which is not bad, in general. It has a lot of features, but it can get kinda messy when we start to mix daily operations (tasks) with tactical placeholders (projects) or even strategic objectives.

Also, everybody has access to our ClickUp workspace. They have quite a good pricing model, so having a lot of devs does not mean brutal costs. Unfortunately, it is not as great for high-level practices. For example, when an employee plans to take some days off, it's a pain to reflect it everywhere.

We use other tools as well. We use Notion as a knowledge base, Toggl for time tracking, Slack for communication,... and when it gets tough, we go back to the good-old spreadsheets. But spreadsheets get lost easily. Or they get obsolete. Or there are too many of them. It's just not that convenient.

---

### The desired goal

My idea is to find the "holy grail" for project managers where we can coordinate and closely work with Sales, HR, and the C-level. Not many people (~5) are expected to work with this tool. We expect a *program manager* who will be responsible for maintaining this tool and making the most out of it. Ideally, it could have an open API, so we can integrate it with other tools.

It should make *resource management* a breeze. Ideally, it can be shared with the top-level management and used for communicating/reporting the state of the hot topics of our company (i.e. the second challenge).

On the other hand, it should not be an overkill that will have thousands of features that will make it super hard to use. It should be complex enough to cover the two challenges, but simple enough so it could still be considered beneficial to our current state.